# MSVS C++ 2012: how to disable compiling-while-editting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

MSVS C++ constantly checks my code as I edit and mark compile errors/warning with "red wavy underline".

I don't want to see these red wavy underlines. I want to see my errors only when I build.

Is it possible to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options->TextEditor

Then choose C/C++->Advanced and turn off what you don't like. There are also some parameters in General that you may want to turn off (autocompletion).

Comment: Thanks Matthieu
IntelliSense -> "Disable Error Reporting" did it.